# How to find applications running in Ubuntu desktop, usage and idle time through scripts

Tags: desktop-environments, monitoring

I wish to monitor the names of applications open in Ubuntu ##desktop including their usage time and idle time. Is there a way to accomplish this through a backend script?

Comment: [ActivityWatch][1] gives the results in form of json output.

  [1]: https://activitywatch.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `htop` which monitors tasks in your system.
This command is usefull to monitor your system tasks.

For installing you can use; `sudo apt install htop` and **Boom!!!**

htop is in your computer. And now you can monitor tasks properly and kill those unwnated tasks in your system.

Here's a image of htop:-[HTOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaFN7.png)

Comment: Madhan, HTOP does not serve the purpose of monitoring a linux Desktop applications. I have tried it.